# WinForms Экспорт таблицы .csv в форму DataGridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, csv

Мне нужно экспортировать данные из файла .csv на форму и чтобы столбцы были разделены. Но получается так, что у меня один столбец:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
public DataTable ReadCsv(string fileName)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
         Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';"))
        {
            //Execute select query
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select *from [{0}]", new FileInfo(fileName).Name), cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Ох, где вы раскопали такой старый способ работы - OleDb. Попробуйте написать `FMT=Delimited(;)`. Если не поможет - откажитесь от этого старья. Используйте, например, библиотеку CsvHelper.

Comment: В excel создайте пустую таблицу, затем на вкладке данные выберите Загрузить из CSV, тогда оно загрузится в Excel нормально. А так, все верно про CsvHelper.